# Uwp text rendering for a custom text box

Tags: textbox, uwp, richeditbox

I'm currently developing a custom text box for a word processing uwp app and, while I have seen the Windows.Ui.Core.Text library for text input managing, I can't understand how do the default textbook and richeditbox controls render their text? I suppose that they use a low level library, instead of using textblock controls,  but I can't find which they use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may render text using **Win2D**. Check here: https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Text_CanvasTextLayout.htm

And samples here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/win2d-example-gallery/9nblgggxwt9f

Comment: I see that Win2d is based on direct2d, is viable to use the direct2d library instead of win2d?